# When should you use an empty array in a web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby and several tutorials introduce empty arrays and pushing values in them.

I googled "When are empty arrays used?" and there seems to be no web pages that talk about practical empty array usage.

My assumption is that empty arrays are used when arrays elements are unknown and external input provides the array elements. But I cannot think of any examples...

Comment: We have no idea what you're trying to ask, could you be more specific? Did you come across an issue in code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Applications

Comment: I'm just simply asking when are empty arrays used in a web app...

Comment: lol, I don't understand why I am getting all these down votes when all I am asking is when an empty array in a web application code base...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

One example would be errors when they are encountered. e.g. in validation

```
errors[:base] << "Value must be an integer."
```